# A public static function in a class not executing

Tags: php, html

I have a .php file with HTML code also in it. Through this file I am calling a function in another .php file that resides in a class. The call is not working. It is simply not entering the function in the class.

Below are the codes of first and second file respectively.

```
<div id="sectionGrid">  <!-- Begin of Grid Section -->
    <table id="tblGrid">
        <tr>
        <?php
            require("../Lib/displaygrid.php");
            displaygrid::SetGridWithValues("*","electioncategorymaster");
         ?>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>  <!-- End of Grid Section -->
```

Above is just a section of the first file. Below is the second file entire code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js_cookiefunctions.js"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="DGStyle.css" type="text/css">
<?php
final class displaygrid 
{
    public static function SetGridWithValues($columnNames,$tableName)
    {
                echo $columnNames;
                require 'obfusGrid.php';
                require 'obfusGridSqlDAP.php';
                require("../Config/dbconfig.php");
                // Load the database adapter
                $db = new MySQLAdap(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
                // Load the datagrid class
                $x = new MyDataGrid($db);

                // Set the query
                $x->setQuery($columnNames, $tableName);

                // Add a row selector
                $x->addRowSelect("SetRowInCookie(%ID%);");
                echo $columnNames;
                // Apply a function to a row
                function returnSomething($ID)
                {
                    return strrev($id);
                }
                $x->setColumnType('ID', MyDataGrid::TYPE_FUNCTION, 'returnSomething', '%id%');

                // Print the table
                $x->printTable();

                //Show button to return to keywords entry page
                echo "<br><input id='backbutton' type='button' value='Back' onclick='ReturnBack()';>";
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(cookie['row_id']);</script>";        
    }
}
?>
```

I also want to know whether the links to other files are successfully implemented in the second code? I mean, the Link and Script tag on top.

Comment: Did you check the HTML source code? It might be possible that some stuff did not get displayed, because you are in a table row...

Comment: Your code is a mess. You should really separate classes from markup at the very least. Including a cookie handling script and using link tags in the middle of a table row is not a good idea either... You'd really be better off if you just dropped the class entirely and included plain PHP code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a PHP error. Please turn on error_reporting. Can you try to remove the two lines on the top of this file ../Lib/displaygrid.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js_cookiefunctions.js"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="DGStyle.css" type="text/css">
```

Hope this helps! But turn on error reporting to see where the actual error is.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe problems with include path?

try:

```
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Lib/path/to/required.file.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 )` and `error_reporting ( E_ALL )`

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the first two lines of file ../Lib/displaygrid.php for your code to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js_cookiefunctions.js"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="DGStyle.css" type="text/css">
```

BTW, you should write cleaner code and avoid mixing presentation with code